# Ranks of array elements with respect to lexicographic ordering

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array `A` of length `n` containing strings of length 3. I want to build an array `B` where each string in `A` is replaced by its rank in `A` with respect to the lexicographic ordering. (Note that `A` can have duplicates, so `B` can also have duplicates.)

Assuming that the JavaScript `A.sort()` performs radix sort of `A` in time `O(n)`, how can I build `B` in `O(n)` time from `A`?

**Example:** If `A` is

```
['abb', 'ada', 'bba', 'bba', 'dab', 'bad']
```

then `B` is

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```

(Note: You may assume that array assignments take constant time.)

Comment: `sort` is implemented with radix sort in JavaScript? If so that's interesting, do you have some references?

Comment: Can `A` have duplicates? If so, what should happen?

Comment: Note that you cannot guarantee `O(n)` with `Array#sort()` in JS. We don't have control over what sorting algorithm a specific env uses either.

Comment: Here's an O(sort(n))-time algorithm assuming that associative array ops are O(1)-time: copy A to an array A1. Sort A1. Scan A1 from beginning to end; whenever the element x in position j is not in the associative array Rank, insert Rank[x] = j. Make B by scanning through A doing lookups in Rank. I'd make this an answer if my Javascript weren't so rusty.

Comment: @Randomblue With length-3 strings? Seems plausible to me as a practical assumption. I don't mean to start a holy war, but if you want more control, perhaps you should switch languages.

Comment: Is it okay to approximate array assignment as being constant time?

Comment: What is the need for the answer to this question?

Comment: @Reimius: It's one of the steps in building suffix arrays in `O(n)` time: http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/jacm05-revised.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fastest thing I can think of...

```
function cheese(a){
    var b = [];
    var c = {};//hash references to make lookups really fast
    var d = [];//desired output
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(!c[a[i]])
            b.push(a[i]);
        c[a[i]] = true;
    }
    b.sort();
    for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        c[b[i]] = i;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        d.push(c[a[i]] + 1);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your rewrite slower due to the use of forEach which would create a function scope for every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try, but I don't feel very confident about:

- Sort algorithm consistency across browsers' implementations
- My solution could be simplified, and it's not extensively tested.

Anyway, it seems to give desired result so let's go:

```
Array.prototype.getLexicoGraphic = function() {
    var result = [], 
        sorted = this.slice(0).sort();

    for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i ++) {
        result[i] = sorted.indexOf(this[i]) - (i - sorted.indexOf(sorted[i])) + 1;    
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` runs in `O(n)`, so your algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: True. Answer's not easy :)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance on the topic, but I understand that n^x where x is the number of loops needed to return the final value. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Construct secondary array, which will contain the value alongside with its original index - `O(n)`.

```
[[0, 'abb'], [1, 'ada'], [2, 'bba'], [3, 'bba'], [4, 'dab'], [5, 'bad']] // Stored as 'foo' in the following examples
```

Sort the newly created array using [comparator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - according to your assumption `O(n)` (but I doubt that).

```
foo.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]); });
```

Iterate over the sorted array and create your rank array on the way - `O(n)`.

```
var last = null, rank = 0, result = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    result[foo[i][0]] = (last === null || last.localeCompare(foo[i][1]) != 0) ? ++rank : rank;
    last = foo[i][1];
}
```

Enjoy your `result`.

---

**Update** Another way how to do this is via associative array with indexes:

```
{ 'abb': [0], 'ada': [1], 'bba': [2, 3], 'dab': [4], 'bad': [5] }
```

Then you can create array of keys (hence unique values), sort it and construct your ranking based on that.

Comment: Your first solution does not work. I get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]` as `result`.

Comment: I just used bad variable when constructing the result array. Now its fixed and working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = ['abb', 'ada', 'bba', 'bba', 'dab', 'bad'];
var B = [];

// Assuming slice(0) is O(n) 
var Ap = A.slice(0);
var H = [];

var N = A.length;
var i, index;

// O(n)
A.sort();

// O(n)
for (index = 1, i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // Assuming that H[A[i]] is O(1)
    if (!H[A[i]]) { 
        H[A[i]] = index;
        index++;
    }
}

// O(n)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    B[i] = H[Ap[i]];
}
console.log(B);

// 4 * O(n) === O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of ordinals in O(n) time

```
var a = ...;

var ranks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { ranks[i] = i; }
```

Then you can define a comparator that compares integers by comparing the indexed string

```
function cmp(i, j) {
  return a[i] < a[j] ? -1 : a[i] = a[j] ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Each comparison takes constant time since the strings are constant length.

Then perform your custom sort on `ranks` instead using `cmp` which you stipulated takes linear time.  This will yield `b`.

If you need the sorted version of `a`, you can reconstruct it from `a` and `ranks` in linear time.

```
var aSorted = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  aSorted[i] = a[ranks[i]];
}
```